# Why does adding php:"" to homestead.yaml create a 502 error?

Tags: php, macos, vagrant, homestead

I'm using homestead on macos monterey. I have php 8.1 in my vagrant box but would like to check a site with another php version. I tried

```
- map: site.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/site
      php: "7.4"
```

But adding any `php:""` creates a 502 gateway error for this site - other sites still work when I `vagrant up --provision`.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the internal error log instead of just the HTTP status…?

Comment: What's the best way to do that?

Comment: I've tried finding /var/log/apache2/error.log in vagrant ssh